# Maximum withdrawal from an ATM in the USA

Tags: usa, money, exchange

What is the maximum amount you can withdraw from an ATM in the USA? I have a UK credit and debit card and can use either to withdraw cash.  I know I will be charged a fee so I want to withdraw as much cash as I can to limit the fee.

Comment: Note that you should be very careful when withdrawing cash on a credit card. On most cards you start paying intrest on cash **the moment you withdraw it**, not after your usual payment date. Some cards also have a higher rate of interest for cash advances. If you're from the UK, see MoneySavingExpert's advice on travel cards.

Comment: Check with your own bank, you might have a limit yourself.

Comment: Machines don't all have the same. I've used privately-owned machines that max out at $200; the Wells Fargo ATMs at SFO gave me maxed out (circa 2004) at $1000. Your card may also have a limit; one of mine is $1000 per pull and $2000 per day.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I sense a range, rather than a single number might be a good (and satisfactory) answer to the question. I've not been anywhere where all machines have the same limit.

Comment: I find this question too broad to be answerable.  The USA doesn't have a centralized banking system, and is a rather large country to make generalizations from.  Perhaps specifying what airport you'll be conducting this transaction might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far.  I am currently on holiday from the UK in Arizona and will be heading to California in 2 days time. I will be withdrawing cash from either Flagstaff or San Diego.  I am hoping to withdraw at least $1000.  I know interest is charged as soon as you withdraw but I have loaded my credit card so any withdrawal is paid for straight away.

Comment: @Angie Is there something in particular you need cash for? Depending on your bank or credit card issuer, you might be better off putting everything you can (and my experience when travelling in the US is that's basically everything) directly on your card instead.

Comment: Note that ATMs in the US almost always only dispense $20 bills, so if you do withdraw a large amount, you will have a big stack of currency to deal with.

Comment: There are a number of places that have fee-less ATMs. I am not sure if those would accept out-of-country bank cards, but I don't recall seeing any such exception. I know the Sheetz gas station chain almost always has such machines, but there are some other locations. If you aren't charged a fee, there wouldn't be much reason to worry about the max, as long as such ATMs are accessible.

Answer (score 7):

Limits are set both by your bank, which imposes per-day and per-withdrawal limits, and by the machine, which imposes a per-withdrawal limit but will allow you to make as many individual withdrawals -- for an additional fee of course -- as you like.

Many independently owned ATMs have $200 limits, which is ridiculous if you ask me, but the limit on most bank-owned ATMs varies from $300 to $800.

Comment: Seconded. In my experience, Bank of America ATMs max out at 800 USD per withdrawal with the official reason that they can only dispense 40 bills at a time (and they dispense 20 Dollar bills).

Comment: I've personally withdrawn $1000 from BofA ATMs before.  40 bill limit is also only for older ATMs but the new ones take more though they don't announce it.

Answer (score 0):

You're generally limited by your bank's or credit card issuer's limitation on the daily withdrawal of cash from the ATM.

Depending on the type of account you have and the amount of money you have in it that amount may vary.  I've known some people who have had business accounts that allowed them to withdraw $1500 daily, and I've seen them getting that much out too.  So you should check with the credit card issuer how much you will be allowed to get rather than checking how much an ATM will let you have.

In addition you should check how the fees you pay will get calculated because I've also known some that are calculated as an amount per $100 withdrawn and so on but you don't pay any fees to the ATM holder (PNC Bank for example).

Comment: So the only limit is the account rules? No limits per machine? Hmmm.

Comment: @CMaster I've not seen one.  The limit is placed by the card issuer.  The machine will let you withdraw up to your limit.

Comment: @CMaster Well, the final limit is the amount of money in the machine. But while it's probably possible for an ATM owner to set a withdrawal limit, I've never seen one posted, whereas the institution where the account is held may impose per-transaction, per-machine, per-account, or per-day limits.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask your bank; they are the ones that have the final say - and they may also be able to tell you which ATMs to use.

As there is very little in difference between GBP and USD - your only challenge will be to find an ATM that isn't restricted by the ATM operator on foreign cards.

If you were traveling to a country where the exchange rate is considerably different, then you would be limited by the maximum allowed by the ATMs (as the majority of ATMs will only dispense the local currency) - which would be different than what your bank allows on the card.

Keep in mind that carrying cash is not as much of an issue as it used to be; card acceptance is almost universal in the US.